# How to integrate MVC4 with SmartAdmin?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using SmartAdmin for UI purpose and MVC4 for coding. SmartAdmin CSS is not supported inside

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm()) {
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

           <fieldset>
            <div class="row">
              <section class="label col col-1">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, new { @style = "text-align:left" })     
              < /section>
             <section class="col col-4">
              <label class="input"> <i class="icon-append fa fa-user"></i>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name, null, new { @placeholder = "Enter Name" })
                  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
              </label>
             </section>
             <section class="label col col-1">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Role)
             </section>
             <section class="col col-4">
             <label class="input"> <i class="icon-append fa fa-user"></i>
               @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Role, null, new { @placeholder = "Enter Role" })
                 @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Role)
             </label>
          </section>
         </div>
<p>
    <input type="submit" value="Create" />
</p>
    </fieldset>
        }
```

But by using code above, UI does not looks in proper format. When I remove

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm()) {
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
```

from code then UI looks properly but does not posts values to controller.Now my issue is that, can MVC4 supports SmartAdmin for UI purpose? 
Is there any solution for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a great tutorial for that:

http://myorange.ca/supportforum/question/how-to-integrate-smartadmin-1-4-x-into-asp-net-mvc-5

Answer (score 1):

add the "smart-form" tag into the class field like below to activate it.

```
Html.BeginForm("ACTIONNAME", "CONTROLLERNAME", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "smart-form ", id = "myID" }))
```

But if you are starting with smartadmin and MVC, i highly recommand you to follow the tutorial:
http://myorange.ca/supportforum/question/how-to-integrate-smartadmin-1-4-x-into-asp-net-mvc-5

Answer (score 0):

I use a bootstrap based template.  It works very well for me, in my code I do not use the form helper, so more along the lines of .  Try doing this instead to see if that helps.  It is entirely possible that the helper is allocating a class to the form which throws out the CSS formatting.  Using something like Firebug to look at the effective CSS will help you.